# Replicating graphics in ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

Why do these graphics get so different using the `plot` and `ggplot2`? How to replicate the graphs made with the `hist()` command using the `ggplot()` command?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ssmrob)
require(gridExtra)

data(MEPS2001)
attach(MEPS2001)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(ambexp,ylim = c(0,3500),xlim=c(0,20000) ,xlab = "Ambulatory Expenses", ylab = "Freq.",main = "")
hist(lnambx,ylim = c(0,800),xlim=c(0,12), xlab = "Log Ambulatory Expenses", ylab = "Freq.",main = "")
```

[image]

```
df <- data.frame(MEPS2001)
attach(df)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
g1 <- ggplot(data = MEPS2001, aes(ambexp)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white") +
  xlab("Ambulatory Expenses") +
  ylab("Freq.") +
  xlim(c(0, 20000)) +
  ylim(c(0,3500))

g2 <- ggplot(data = MEPS2001, aes(lnambx)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.5, colour="black", fill="white") +
  xlab("Log Ambulatory Expenses") +
  ylab("Freq.") +
  xlim(c(0, 12)) +
  ylim(c(0,800))

grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `geom_hist` naturally aligns bars so they're centered on a value. By limiting the x-axis to 0 you're cutting off bar that should be centered on 0 (`ggplot` will not show it because it extends into a negative x value). This behavior can be changed to what you want by setting `boundary` in `geom_hist` as below:

```
g1 <- ggplot(data = MEPS2001, aes(ambexp)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=5000, colour="black", fill="white",boundary=0) +
  xlab("Ambulatory Expenses") +
  ylab("Freq.")+
  xlim(c(0,20000)) +
  ylim(c(0,3500)) 

g2 <- ggplot(data = MEPS2001, aes(lnambx)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, colour="black", fill="white",boundary=0) +
  xlab("Log Ambulatory Expenses") +
  ylab("Freq.") +
  xlim(c(0, 12)) +
  ylim(c(0,800))

grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

yelids

[image: Histograms]

Comment: Very thanks @Pdubbs, but because have this message: Warning message:
Removed 6 rows containing non-finite
values (stat_bin).

Comment: @fsbmat that's `ggplot` dropping rows that are larger than your upper limit on the x axis. Run `table(MEPS2001$ambexp>20000)` and you'll see there are six. I believe `hist` does the same thing